# Bayeux server hangs on connect request

Tags: java, websocket, faye, bayeux

this is bugging me for almost two days.

I'm writing Bayeux client. I use [WebSocket-client](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.2.v20140723/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) library from Jetty and connecting to [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) server.

I open a WS connection to the server (everything localhost) with handshake request:

```
{"channel":"/meta/handshake","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling","websocket"],"version":"1.0"}
```

The client immediately receives a handshake response:

```
{"channel":"/meta/handshake","successful":true,"version":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","cross-origin-long-polling","callback-polling","websocket","eventsource","in-process"],"clientId":"l8xhgf0t5gikcukcknhr5npfx11s5w9","advice":{"reconnect":"retry","interval":0,"timeout":45000}}
```

Then client sends connect request:

```
{"clientId":"l8xhgf0t5gikcukcknhr5npfx11s5w9","connectionType":"websocket","channel":"/meta/connect"}
```

Then the server hangs for 45s (the value of time out) and then sends this response:

```
{"clientId":"l8xhgf0t5gikcukcknhr5npfx11s5w9","channel":"/meta/connect","successful":true,"advice":{"reconnect":"retry","interval":0,"timeout":45000}}
```

last log message on Faye server before it hangs: Ping "l8xhgf0t5gikcukcknhr5npfx11s5w9", 45

But I never receive Ping frame on client side.
I have no idea why the server hangs for those 45s, but I need to resolve this.
Have anyone of you seen this before? Any help/suggestions/hints much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is exactly what a Bayeux server should do.

The server does not "hang"; it holds the request in a [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) fashion.

I don't know much Faye but the [CometD project](http://cometd.org), which defined the [Bayeux protocol specification](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_bayeux), implements a server in the same way, where the `/meta/connect` message request is held for the timeout value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused because I selected the transport to be websocket, therefore I expected the message to be returned immediately. Next time I need to read the specs more carefully.

Comment: @TomasZaoral as the CometD project leader I will be interested in what language / platform you are writing the Bayeux client. The CometD project has a Java and a JavaScript one not sure about the Faye project.